# Bootstrap opening wrong modal in view with multiple modals - Yii 2.0

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, yii2

I'm getting strange behavior from several modals that I have in a view that has multiple modal buttons.  When I click on a modal in one section of the view it shows me a modal that is rendered in a different part of the view (that should pop up with a different button).  The modals where I'm seeing the error are loaded with Ajax.  When I look at the HTML behind the modal it is what I expect it to be, and then when I click on the modal itself the content does not reflect the HTML behind it?  This was working fine previously and I can't figure out what changed.  But it seems like it isn't binding the event to the correct button after bring in the modal elements with Ajax.

This is the HTML behind the modal button that is not rendering correctly when I click the button.

```
<button id="859" class="editicon" data-target="#w0" style="background:#ffffff; border:0" data-get="1" data-toggle="modal" title="Pulse New Notification" type="button">
<i class="fa fa-heartbeat fa-2x text-danger"></i>
</button>
<div id="w0" class="fade modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button class="close" aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">×</button>
<h3>Edit or Pulse Blog Updates</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<div id="editevent134" class="modal-body" name="edit-modal">
<div class="form-group row">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
<input id="templateid134" class="templateheaders form-control eventname149-104134" type="text" placeholder="Enter Event Name.." ,="" data-req="0" style="width:100%;" name="eventname">
<div id="headerhelpmsg134"></div>
</div>
</div>
<br>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4">
<label class="control-label">
Blog Link
<span style="color:#990000;">*</span>
</label>
<input id="pubselectid707-104-134" class="form-control 149-104-134" type="text" data-type="15" data-md="0" data-dd="0" style="height:33px; width:350px;" data-req="0" name="pubselect707">
<div id="helpmsg707-104-134"></div>
</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4">
<label class="control-label">Tags </label>
<select id="pubselectid709-104-134" class="149-104-134 crystal149 form-control select2-hidden-accessible" data-krajee-select2="select2_c36fab6b" data-req="1" data-md="1" data-type="19" data-dd="1" data-child="0" style="width: 190px; display: none;" size="4" multiple="" name="pubselect709[]" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
<option value="709-12666">Oveido</option>
<option value="709-12667">Spain</option>
<option value="709-12668">Asturius</option>
</select>
<span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--krajee" dir="ltr" style="width: 100%;">
<span class="selection">
<span class="select2-selection select2-selection--multiple" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" aria-autocomplete="list" role="combobox" tabindex="0">
</span>
<span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</span>
<div id="helpmsg709-104-134"></div>
</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4">
<label class="control-label">Short Note </label>
<input id="pubselectid708-104-134" class="form-control 149-104-134" type="text" style="height:65px; width:600px;" data-type="4" data-md="0" data-dd="0" data-req="1" name="pubselect708">
<div id="helpmsg708-104-134"></div>
</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4">
<label class="control-label">
Date Posted
<span style="color:#990000;">*</span>
</label>
<div id="pubselectid706-104-134-kvdate" class="input-group date">
<span class="input-group-addon kv-date-calendar" title="Select date">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
</span>
<span class="input-group-addon kv-date-remove" title="Clear field">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
</span>
<input id="pubselectid706-104-134" class="form-control 149-104-134 krajee-datepicker" type="text" data-krajee-kvdatepicker="kvDatepicker_00000000" data-datepicker-type="2" data-datepicker-source="pubselectid706-104-134-kvdate" data-related="0" data-type="5" data-md="0" data-dd="0" data-req="0" readonly="" value="03/12/2016" name="pubselect706"></div>
<div id="helpmsg706-104-134"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="form-group row">
<div class="col-sm-3" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 45px">
<div id="pulsebtn149-104-134" class="existingevent" data-gdata="0">
<button class="btn" style="padding:10px 70px 10px 70px; color:#990000;border-radius:5px; background:#ffffff; border-width: 2px; border-color: #990000;" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Pulse</button>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 10px">
<div id="savebtn149-104-134" class="editsavecontainer" data-gdata="0">
<button class="btn btn-danger" style="padding:10px 23px 10px 23px; color:#007ACC; border-radius:5px; background:#ffffff; border-width: 2px; border-color: #007ACC;" type="button">Update Template Only</button>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3" style="float:right; padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;">
<div class="col-sm-1" style="margin:0px 45px 0px 0px">
<button class="btn btn-default" style="padding:10px 40px 10px 40px; color:#5f5f5f; border-radius:5px; background:#eeeeee; border-width: 2px; border-color: grey;" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Cancel</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>< /div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

UPDATE:

ok, I think I figured this out.  Seems like the modals that get rendered with AJAX are getting assigned the same id in some cases as the modal that is rendered when the page loads.  Therefore, when "data-target= id" gets passes to the event I'm thinking it's picking the first one in the DOM.  Anyone know of a good way to assign a unique id to the modals that get loaded with AJAX and point the button "data-target" attribute to that id with bootstrap?

UPDATE 2:

```
public function getId($autoGenerate = true)
{
    if ($autoGenerate && $this->_id === null) {
        //add rand() to the counter to ensure unique id
        $this->_id = static::$autoIdPrefix . static::$counter++ .rand();
    }

    return $this->_id;
}
```

Comment: solved..I had to adjust how my Widget class was assigning the id to the modals that got rendered with ajax.

Comment: more specifically in Yii's Widget Class there is a method getId($autoGenerate = true) .. I added php rand() function to this to ensure a unique id for any elements that get created with the Widget class.